# memory bandwidth of convolutional layer: numbers calculations

Tags: deep-learning, memory-bandwidth

In [this](https://culurciello.medium.com/computation-and-memory-bandwidth-in-deep-neural-networks-16cbac63ebd5) article, the author is mentioning that

> Convolutions: for convolution operation, the bandwidth requirements are usually lower, as an input map data can be used in several convolution operation in parallel, and convolution weights are relatively small.

> For example: a 13 x 13 pixel map in a 3x3 convolution operation from 192 input maps to 192 output maps (as, for example, in Alexnet layer 3) requires: ~4MB weight data and ~0.1MB input data from memory. This may require about 3.2 GB/s to be performed on a 128 G-ops/s system with ~99% efficiency (SnowFlake Spring 2017 version). The bandwidth usage is low is because the same input data is used to compute 192 outputs, albeit with different small weight matrices.

When I tried to re-calculate these numbers, something is missing:

Let's say that one element of conv. layer requires 3x3x192 x2 (for additions and multiplications)
output is 11x11 (assuming no padding) therefore for one out_channel we require 418176 and there are 192 out_channels, therefore, MACs needed are 80,289,792.
with a system at 128G-GFLOPS, 80,289,792/(128*2^30) = time required is 0.000584

I don't know how he arrived at bandwidth requirement of 3.2GB/s and secondly how did weights data is 4 MB..

because, # of weights are 3x3x192x192x4 (4 for FP32) = 1.26 MB